# knockout.js - mapping plugin plus other properties

Tags: mapping, knockout.js

I want to map a very large object with many fields into a javascript object using this technique:

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

However, I also want to be able to add other properties/functions to the viewModel.  How would that be done?

**EDIT** -- here is the answer:

The answer to this question is the following:

```
function MyModelOject(data) {
    var self = this;    
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    // other functions go here
}
```

Comment: Yup, I tried.  It says I can't for three more hours. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function MyModelOject(data) {
    var self = this;    
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    // other functions go here
}
```